# find_or_initialize_by and Nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

So just a quick description. In the '`Users/Show`' I have a form for `Clubs` which accepts nested attributes for `CurrentClubs`. I have a text field for the name of the club. If you enter in a name that already exists, the nested attributes for `CurrentClubs` create a record using the id of the club that is already created. If the club does not exist, it creates the club and then add the new clubs id to the `:club_id` field in the `CurrentClub` nested attributes.

The problem is NOT trying to get the `id` from the newly created club, it does this well. The problem is trying to get the `id` from the already existing club and placing it into the nested attribute. For some reason it is not being entered into the parameters.

So in short, if I enter a new club that does not exist, the nested attributes are entered perfectly and the club is created, if the club does exist, it catches the nested attributes except the `:club_id`.

The server keeps showing this:

```
  Processing by ClubsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"club"=>{"name"=>"Pacha", "current_clubs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"club_id"=>"", "user_id"=>"2"}}, "state"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"+", "authenticity_token"=>"OC4x6CxP3lfaSSneGRjiPDSm6ElxAbj2mGukOVD5VFc=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "locale"=>"en"}

Clubs#Controller
  def create
    @club = Club.find_or_initialize_by_name(params[:club][:name])
    @club.attributes = params[:club] unless @club.persisted?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @club.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@club) }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to(clubs_url, :notice => 'club could not be created.') }
      end
    end
  end

Users#Controller
         def show
          @club = Club.new
          1.times { @club.current_clubs.build }
         end

Club.rb
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :state_id, :country_id, :name, :rating, :club_promoters_attributes, :past_clubs_attributes, :current_clubs_attributes
has_many :current_clubs
has_many :past_clubs
has_many :club_promoters
belongs_to :state

accepts_nested_attributes_for :club_promoters
accepts_nested_attributes_for :past_clubs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :current_clubs

  scope :by_name, lambda { |s|
    where("name LIKE ?", "#{s.strip}%")
  }


  def full_name
    "#{name}"
  end

  default_scope :order => 'clubs.name ASC'

end

Current_clubs#form
<div>
<%= form_for(@club) do |f| %>

     <input id="search_club" type="text" placeholder="Enter Club" />

    <%= f.hidden_field :name, :class => 'name' %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :state, :value => @user.state_id %>

      <%= f.fields_for :current_clubs do |current_clubs_fields| %>
        <%= current_clubs_fields.hidden_field :club_id, :value => @club.id %>

        <%= current_clubs_fields.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @user.id %>

      <% end %>




    <%= f.submit "+" %>
<% end %>

<script>
    $("#search_club").bind('keyUp blur', function (event) {
        var stt = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().find(".name").val(stt);
    });

</script>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance, and forgive me if I haven't used the right names for things, I'm not a great developer. Using rails 3.09 and ruby 1.87

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the UsersController code is missing, but I can't see the action to which the code in `UsersController` belongs. Do you try to set the `@club` to any existing record anywhere (e.g. `@club = @user.clubs.first || Club.new`)?  `@club = Club.new` will always return a blank id...

Comment: Do you want the whole UsersController?

Comment: I tried @club = Club.first || Club.new, simply because Users haven't got a has_many relationship with clubs. It seems to be creating multiple CurrentClubs...

Comment: I think that you are on the right track. I'm just playing around with the code. But you're right, I think my problem is in the UserController with the .new

Comment: I'm having trouble with the users controller code. I don't know what to put. I tried Club.first, Club.find(params[:id]), both of them create multiple records in CurrentClubs and when I create a new club it overwrites an old one. It is passing the clubs id, which is what I wanted, but causing other problems too. Any other ideas for the UsersController?

Comment: Can you provide some context on what you are trying to display and what you're trying to make happen?  It seems you're trying to show a user's profile page with current clubs they are associated with and allow them to be associated with new ones?  If that's the case, then likely the architecture needs to be remodeled.  you may be able to scope calls or use a join table for something like club affiliations.  Seperate tables and models for current_clubs and past_clubs is bad design in my experience, though I'm no expert either!